# Facebook Registration PLugin question

Tags: facebook, plugins, registration, facebook-iframe

I'm working on using the fb registration plugin on my sites.  Sometimes a site doesn't support iframes. Is there another version of this script below that works without iframes or is there a workaround?

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?
         client_id=113869198637480&
         redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fecho%2F&
         fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email"
    scrolling="auto"
    frameborder="no"
    style="border:none"
    allowTransparency="true"
    width="100%"
    height="330">
</iframe>
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean by the idea that a site 'doesn't support iframes', but to answer your question, the Registration plugin is only available as an iFrame and i'm not aware of any other way to use it.

There's no reason you couldn't implement the Registration plugin's functionality yourself using the regular APIs if you needed to for some reason. The registration plugin just optimises a particular use-case ('sign up for a site with the possibility of using Facebook account information') and makes it faster to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. You can use the XFBML version of the plugin. This allows you to not only do what you are asking but to validate custom fields. This is what I choose to use on my application. However, I am not sure if fb is going to deprecate this or not come Jan 1st. Considering there is no replacement, it would be a little messed up if they did. For information on how to use and implement this see this link:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/advanced/

Brandon